# ASP.NET Core 3.1 app on IIS Express: “This site can't be reached” and "The connection was reset"

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-express

I have developed ASP.NET project in Visual Studio 2019. When I try to run the project with IIS Express, the webpage says “This site can't be reached” and "The connection was reset".

In taskbar I can see that IIS Express is working and I'm able to debug and step though my code till the very end successfully so I know the service is executing fine without any errors.

[Site can`t be reached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjkbF.png)

I created a new project, just to ensure that there weren't any errors within my config or build files. When I run the new project, I get the same result.

I tried with other browsers as well, but still the same error.

I repaired the Visual Studio using the Visual Studio Installer, and reset everything to default, and had no success with that.

I tried to delete hidden vs. folder and had no success.

Any advice on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: If you start the new project without IIS express, does it work?

Comment: Just reboot your workstation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by deleting Kaspersky Antivirus.